# asp.net dropdown list default value that does not exist in sql table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net, asp.net-4.5

hi this is my first question on this website

I have a web form with a drop down list, which is being populated from my database which is sql-server 2012.

my table has values like genderID and genderName and it populates the drop down list but I also want to show the default value when the page load event fire "Select gender".

I can add this value in the database to be shown in drop down but this is not the perfect solution as this would mean I have entered a data in sql server which is not a valid data. how can I show this default value in the drop down list which doesnt really exist in the sql server table.

my code behind:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{

        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.Gender", con))
        { 
            con.Open();
            DropDownList1.DataSource =  cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "GenderName";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

When the page loads it should show "Select Gender" in the drop down list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have to add an entry in database to show that default value in your drop down list. You can simply initialize an ListItem object and insert it to the drop down list at index 0.

Remember your drop down list is a collection of ListItem objects, so initialize an object of ListItem type and add it to the drop down list.

Something like ......

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.Gender", con))
    { 
        con.Open();
        DropDownList1.DataSource =  cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "GenderName";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();

        ListItem li = new ListItem("Select Gender", "-1");
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, li);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but I normally do it this way on the Client side

            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPattern" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataValueField="Location" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true">
                <asp:ListItem Value="ALL">Pattern</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>

Answer (score 1):

After data-binding to the dropdownlist, do this:

```
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select gender","")
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work after you bind:

```
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Gender","-1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add the item using a UNION ALL in your select statement.

Here is the example:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select 'Select Gender' genderName, 0 genderID UNION ALL select genderName, genderId from Gender", con))
    { 
        con.Open();
        DropDownList1.DataSource =  cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "genderName";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "genderID";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }
}
```